# Is aliasing the cause of the error in this simple group by error?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am a bit new to SQL Developer and I am getting error "not a group by expression"

`select cmp.company_name, sum( inv.total_price ), inv.invoice_date FROM   companies cmp join invc_header inv on cmp.cmp_auto_key = inv.cmp_auto_key group by cmp.company_name`

Maybe aliasing is the cause? I have read as many posts as I could but cant find the snag.

Jeff

Comment: If a column in your SELECT isn't also in the GROUP BY, it needs an aggregate function (max, sum, etc) wrapping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select CMP.COMPANY_NAME
     , sum(INV.TOTAL_PRICE)
     , INV.INVOICE_DATE
  from COMPANIES CMP
  join INVC_HEADER INV on CMP.CMP_AUTO_KEY = INV.CMP_AUTO_KEY
 group by CMP.COMPANY_NAME, inv.invoice_date;
```

Your 3rd column isn't a 'rollup' so you also need to group by on the INVOICE_DATE...unless you wanted to change that to a MIN() or AVG()...

Comment: Hi Jeff, I am trying to get totals from each company_name.  When I group by inv.invoice_date it does what it is supposed to but does not sum the total for each company.

Comment: I used Max in the select statement for inv.invoice_date but not sure if this is the correct way.  It seems to work as it used to in Access.

Comment: select cmp.company_name, sum (inv.total_price ), max (inv.invoice_date) 
 FROM   companies cmp join invc_header inv on cmp.cmp_auto_key = inv.cmp_auto_key
 group by cmp.company_name

Comment: just take out the invoice date competely

Comment: That works for sure but my where statement needs it.

Comment: select cmp.company_name, sum (inv.total_price ), max (inv.invoice_date) 
 FROM   companies cmp join invc_header inv on cmp.cmp_auto_key = inv.cmp_auto_key
 group by cmp.company_name;
 where inv.invoice_date > '2018-01-01' and inv.invoice_date < '2019-01-01'

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  Mostly working. I just have to figure out my snag with the date command.

Comment: you can use a column in a WHERE clause w/o having it in the SELECT